# Firebase Java admin SDK error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-admin

I am trying to verify ID Token of user. Whenever I call the verifyIdToken function the following error is thrown:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: projectId must be set

Here is the servlet code:

```
public class GeneratorInfoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    FirebaseApp app = null;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) {
        InputStream serviceAccount = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/service_key.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://project-id.firebaseio.com/")
                .build();

        this.app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        StringBuffer tokenBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                tokenBuffer.append(line);

            this.verifyToken(tokenBuffer.toString());
            out.print("{'success': false}");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.print(e);
            out.print("{'success': true}");
        }
    }

    private void verifyToken(String idToken) {
        System.out.println(app);
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance(this.app).verifyIdToken(idToken)
                .addOnSuccessListener(decodedToken -> {
                    String uid = decodedToken.getUid();
                    System.out.println(uid);
                }).addOnFailureListener(e -> System.out.println(e));
    }
}
```

I've been going through documentation and I didn't find a way how to set the project id directly. However I think it shouldn't be necessary in the first place since it's already written in the service_key and database url.

Thanks!

Edit:

Regular Java SDK (non admin) has setApplicationId("PROJECT_ID") function built in FirebaseOptions builder. However there is no such option in Admin SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am initializing my Firebase App a little bit different, see my code

```
InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/service_key.json");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setServiceAccount(in)
                    .setDatabaseUrl(".....")
                    .build();
```

This is working for me with Admin SDK Version 4.0.4

Comment: I've been using the newest Admin SDK 4.1.1 in which the setServiceAccont method is deprecated. I tried to downgrade to your version after which I've been getting the NullPointerException. It turned out that the InputStream is null and the newer SDK version is not checking for null value and is throwing the misleading "projectId must be set" error. Thanks a lot, your comment got me to the core of the issue

Comment: Gah, sorry about that! We will get this updated in an upcoming release so we throw a better error for this case.

Comment: No problem. Thanks